# various forms of getline()

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I read that this form of getline:

```
getline(char *buf, streamsize num)
```

But I recently came across this getline function:

```
getline(cin,x);
```

where `x` is a `string`.

How is this ?

Comment: [Function overloading](http://www.codersource.net/c/c-tutorials/c-tutorial-function-overloading.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is a member function of `std::istream`. And the second one is a free standalone function. You've overloaded functions for both.

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

Comment: what do you mean by a stand alone function ?

Comment: @steve: that it is not a member function of any class.

Comment: It has to be a function of some class...Am i wrong in my statement ?

Comment: @steve: Why? Is `printf` a function of some class? In C++, you can define free functions as well, just line one can do in C.

Answer (score 0):

The former is a member function of `basic_istream`.

The later is a free function.

Comment: @steve: A free function is a function that is not a member-function. If you do not know that, you should read a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).